# What is a good way to make all h tags display as normal text?

Tags: html, css

Using CSS only not (SASS/SCSS) what is a good way to make all text in h tags display as regular text?

Comment: Define "regular text." CSS seems like a fine approach; [what have you tried so far?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I did do `h1, h2,` but that seems like a pretty clunky approach. And it is within another CSS finders so it creates a lot of duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all)`:`[`unset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset).

> The CSS `all` shorthand property resets all properties, apart from
>   [`unicode-bidi`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unicode-bidi) and [`direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction), to their initial or inherited value.
>
> The `unset` CSS keyword is the combination of the [`initial`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial) and
>   [`inherit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inherit) keywords. Like these two other CSS-wide keywords, it
>   can be applied to any CSS property, including the CSS shorthand
>   [`all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all). This keyword *resets* the property to its inherited value if
>   it inherits from its parent or to its initial value if not.

```css
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  all: unset;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  all: unset;
}
```

```html
<h1>Header1</h1>
<h2>Header2</h2>
Text
```

Comment: Might want to take note of the browser support on these.

Answer (score 0):

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a `normal/400 font-weight` for the header tags. The standard `line-height/(margin-top and margin-bottom) is around 1.1em`.

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6
{
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 1.1em;
    margin-bottom: 1.1em;
}
```

Here is a *JSFiddle* I made: http://jsfiddle.net/zd06ef75/1/

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{
   font-weight: normal;
   font-size: 12px;
}
```